# How to add standalone attachment to a document in CouchDB using Curl?

Tags: curl, couchdb

I'm using CouchDB 1.5.1 on Linux. Before trying to implement in libCurl, I'm trying to do this using curl. I want to add a document, then add an attachment (standalone) to that same document in a separate call. I can successfully add a document to CouchDB as follows:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://admin:secret@localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc' 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{  
        "name":"john",
        "last":"doe",
        "age":"30"
    }'
```

The problem I'm having is adding an attachment after the document is added. If I understand correctly, I have to have the revision of the document to add the attachment. Also, it would seem that anything under '_attachments' must be base64 encoded. The base64 also seems to help with documents containing new lines and carriage returns so I thought about encoding all my docs, both text and binary, in base64. I also realize I could just use the base64 cmd. I've been trying something like the following:

```
curl -X POST 'http://admin:secret@localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc?rev=3-a0241af37764c0389eb0d3c0a9a6540d'  
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
        "_attachments": {
            "testfile.txt": {
                "content-type":"text/plain", 
                "data":"'$(openssl base64 < ./testfile)'" 
            } 
        } 
    }'
```

Currently, I'm getting lots of the following errors ...error.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: b3IgaW1wbGVtZW50CiAgICAgdGhlbSB5b3Vyc2VsZi4KCiAgQ1VSTE9QVF9XUklU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close! You just need to add double qoutes around the output of the shell command so it treated as a string.

```
curl -X POST 'http://admin:secret@localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc?rev=3-a0241af37764c0389eb0d3c0a9a6540d'  
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "_attachments": {
        "testfile.txt": {
            "content-type":"text/plain", 
            "data":"'"$(openssl base64 < ./testfile)"'" 
        } 
    } 
}'
```

Comment: Well, that changed the error to ... {"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}

Comment: Another follow-up, I see if I just use the database location "mydb" and not add the document name, then it will add, but not to the document. PUT works, and I know POST will generate the doc id for you, but doesn't it also allow for using the document name in creating a doc?